# Logical Ring Buffer with Semaphore Synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, buffer, semaphore, buffer-overflow

So this is my implementation of a Logical Ring Buffer with Semaphore Synchronization - it is an assignment and most everything here is as described in the book, concerning the implementation of the buffer and semaphores.

Funny thing is this will throw some odd errors most notably `Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location 0x...` for which I can't really find anything online as to what the cause of this is. I assume it might be the accessing of a global variable, but 9/10 times the program will run successfully (assuming I tell VS to continue), the times it does not it is only the last comparison of integers at index 99 of the 2 int arrays.

This is the main method and producer / consumer functions. There is some global variable declaration and initialization, then the Pro/Con threads are created, started, and waited on, finally the results are compared.

```
#include <iostream>     // cout, cin, ignore
#include <thread>       // thread, join
#include <random>       // rand

/* the number of 'messages' to pass between processes */
const size_t NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES = 100;

/* integer arrays for checking messages after passing */
int PRODUCED_MESSAGES[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES];
int CONSUMED_MESSAGES[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES];

/* the logical ring buffer for thread message passing */
LogicalRingBuffer BUFF; // not initiaslized yet ...

void producer_process() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
        PRODUCED_MESSAGES[i] = rand();
        BUFF.insert(PRODUCED_MESSAGES[i]);
    }
}

void consumer_process() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {
        CONSUMED_MESSAGES[i] = BUFF.remove();
    }
}

int main(int agrc, char* argv[]) {
    BUFF = LogicalRingBuffer(); /* initializes the buffer */

    /* creating the producer and consumer process threads */
    std::thread t1(producer_process), t2(consumer_process);

    /* wait for both threads to complete before comparisons */
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    /* iterating through the contents of both integer arrays */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; i++) {

        /* printing the contents of the arrays to terminal */
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] " << PRODUCED_MESSAGES[i]
            << " <-> " << CONSUMED_MESSAGES[i] << std::endl;

        /* inform user and exit program if comparison fails */
        if (PRODUCED_MESSAGES[i] != CONSUMED_MESSAGES[i]) {
            std::cout << "SYNCHRONIZATION FAILURE!" << std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore(); return -1;
        }
    }


    /* inform user of succesful message passing results */
    std::cout << "ACTION COMPLETED SUCCESFULLY" << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore(); return 0;
}
```

And this is the Buffer/Semaphore implementation. I tried to follow the book to a T, and given that almost every time this runs it is successful (other than throwing errors during runtime) I think the synchronicity is stable in this.

```
struct LogicalRingBuffer{
private:
    /* the standard size of the ring buffer */
    const static size_t SIZEOF_RING_BUFFER = 10;

    /* buffer array and pointers for iteration */
    int BUFFER[SIZEOF_RING_BUFFER], *head, *tail;

    /* inserts data into the buffer, and recycles the tail pointer */
    void push(int data) {
        /* insert data into the buffer, increment tail pointer */
        *tail = data;
        ++tail;
        /* if tail pointing at end of BUFFER, reset to the front */
        if (tail == BUFFER + (SIZEOF_RING_BUFFER - 1)) tail = BUFFER;
    }

    /* removes data from the buffer, and recycles the head pointer */
    int pull() {
        /* remove data from the buffer, increment head pointer */
        int R = *head;
        ++head;
        /* if head pointing at end of BUFFER, reset to the front */
        if (head == BUFFER + (SIZEOF_RING_BUFFER - 1)) head = BUFFER;
        /* return the integer data value */
        return R;
    }

    struct Semaphore {

        /* the counting value, number of resources */
        int count{ NULL };

        /* examines resources, holds until ready */
        void wait() {
            while (count <= 0); //busy wait
            --count;
        }

        /* releases aquired resource (increment) */
        void signal() {
            ++count;
        }

    } empty, full, mutex; /* Semaphores for Synchronization */

public:
    /* initializer for LogicalRingBuffer struct */
    LogicalRingBuffer() {
        head = tail = BUFFER;               // all pointers at BUFFER[0]
        empty.count = SIZEOF_RING_BUFFER;   // number of open positions
        mutex.count = 1;                    // a binary semaphore, mutex
        full.count = 0;                     // number of used positions
    }

    /* semaphore synchronized insertion of data */
    void insert(int data) {
        empty.wait();   // decrements available positions in buff
        mutex.wait();   // waits to gain mutual exlusion lock
        push(data);     // pushes the data into the ring buff
        mutex.signal(); // releases the mutual exclusion lock
        full.signal();  // increments count of buffered datums
    }

    /* semaphore synchronized removal of data */
    int remove() {
        int data{ NULL };   // initialize return data
        full.wait();    // decrements count of buffered items
        mutex.wait();   // waits to gain mutual exlusion lock
        data = pull();  // pulls the data from the ring buff
        mutex.signal(); // releases the mutual exlusion lock
        empty.signal(); // increments avilable positions in buff
        return data;        // return integer data
    }

};
```

I guess I just want this to run without any hiccups, so am I missing something here? Because I'm fairly certain the logic is correct and this is something that maybe Visual Studio does, or who knows...

Answer (score 0):

The two threads you create both attempt to lock the mutex by calling `Semaphore::wait()`.  However, there is nothing preventing the threads from reading and writing to the mutex's `count` variable at the same time.  This results in undefined behavior which can cause the system errors you are seeing.  You are on the right track in your implementation, but at some point the program has to go to the OS for *actual* thread-safety.  You need to use either the standard library's thread-safety mechanisms to protect concurrent access to this variable or your OS's low-level mechanisms, like Windows's [critical sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx).

C++11's standard library implements `std::mutex` which can be used to protect concurrent access to variables which are shared between threads.  However, it's implementation is likely as high-level as the one you are trying to implement yourself, so it would make more sense to discard your own implementation in favor of the standard library's.

Comment: do you not think the `while (count <= 0);` in `Semaphore::wait()`loop will maintain mutual exclusion on the `count` variable?

Comment: @whatfield It will not, there is nothing preventing multiple threads from reading or writing to that variable at the same time.  This is just how C++ and many other programming languages work.

Comment: @whatfield If you want a quick fix, try making the count variable type `std::atomic<int>`.  `std::atomic` is a data wrapper that makes a variable inherently thread-safe.  There are performance implications with using atomics in their default state, but I imagine it doesn't matter for this particular case.

Comment: thanks I am looking into the atomic wrapper but it didn't like a simple copy paste at first so there's probably more to it. But what still doesn't make sense is the mutual exclusion of count? I mean if there is a while loop holding until count is zero or greater, and count was less than zero, doesn't that exclude the thread from accessing the count variable in a write mode?

Comment: @whatfield Consider the case where both threads execute the `while (count <= 0)` check at the same time when `count` is zero.  Both threads see the value of `count` to be 0 and then go on to decrement `count` at the same time.  Then both threads are free to execute and the mutex hasn't helped.  In reality, your program's state is undefined as soon as concurrent reads/writes occur, but this is a conceptual example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: thank you fore the help, you're case has definitely occurred at runtime with this code. I began to look at the atomic types but they required a copy constructor to exist and I'm trying to limit the LOC here. So what I ended up doing was compiling with GCC (suppressing warnings: -w) and throwing a random thread sleep time before entering the while loop (between 20 & 100 ms). I'm going to use this as sort of a focus point on the research report. I fully understand that this only masks the problem, but that is the point of research right?

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to the problem, compiling in Cygwin GCC with: `g++ *.cpp -std=c++11 -w` and rewriting the `Semaphore::wait()` method as follows:

```
void wait() {
    /* the next line was added to avoid count being accessed simultaneously, vvv */
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 10)); // <---
    while (count <= 0); /* BUSY WAIT */
    --count;
}
```

I plan on running more tests, but so far I have had exactly 0 conflicts when using the thread sleep.